# Saving code edits to Salesforce & GitHub Gists simultaneously

Tags: apex, mavensmate, git, github

I currently use a slightly crude combination [GitHub Gists](https://gist.github.com/) + [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) + [Atom](https://atom.io/) to save backups of my Apex code & to keep track of my revision history. Plus [MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com/) with Atom to edit my code, which saves any changes that I make in my Salesforce sandbox.

Obviously the common link between the two sets of *repositories* is the Atom editor. Is it possible to combine my directories (or use some other method) so that when I hit save in Atom, the changes are pushed to both GitHub desktop (where they can then be committed to an existing Gist) & to my Salesforce sandbox, assuming that the changes are compiled successfully?

*Note*

I'm not using GitHub repositories at the moment, as I don't have a team set up in GitHub so I need to be able to share my code with colleagues, by sending links to private Gists.

Comment: Out of scope question: are you using atom with Windows OS? Curious to know as everytime I install and try to get that working with mavensmate in Windows os I get some errors

Comment: Yes I am, I'm using Windows 10 Pro & I don't get any errors (I've never had to fix any either so I can't suggest what the problem might be either, I'm afraid).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try Ant Migration Tool

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool

You coud add an script to pull metadata from one org to another and also save it to, for example, bitbucket.

This is a sample bash script to automate this task

```
    #!/bin/bash
WORKING_DIR=$HOME/Work/
functionResult=0;

function pushToUAT {
    echo 'pushing'
    functionResult=0;
    local antReturnCode=999;

    echo 'Pushing changes from Dev to UAT Step...';
    echo $WORKING_DIR'Dev/scripts/';
    cd $WORKING_DIR'Dev/scripts/';
    ant push;
    antReturnCode=$?
    if [ $antReturnCode -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo 'Changes pushed to UAT!!'
        functionResult=1;
    else
        echo 'Failed to push changes to UAT'
    fi
}

function commitChanges {
  cd 'UAT/';
  git add .
  git commit -m 'UAT Approved';
  git push origin master;
}

function showHelp {
    echo "usage: mttools.sh [ pushUAT | pushPackage | refreshUAT | refreshPackage ]"
}

##### Main
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
  case $1 in
    'pushUAT' )
        pushToUAT
    commitChanges
      exit
      ;;
    * )
      showHelp
      exit 1
  esac
  shift
else
  showHelp
  exit
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately the only script I write is Apex at the moment so ideally, I need a solution that doesn't require me to learn other languages.